# In a specifically ordered set of binary data (ones and zeros), how can you organize them in patterns and from there build a probabilistic network?

Tags: probability, binary-data, excel, pattern-recognition, logic

So I have a set of 1s and 0s. They are listed in a column on excel. They are listed in a specific order. I do not wish to change their order.

So they appear as (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 and so on... 0).

Here is my question: is there anyway to use excel or even another computer program to import this specific set of data into it such that:

For any n set of consecutive values, such that n is any positive number that is not zero, what are all the patterns and what is their ranking from most common to least common -telling me the exact number of times they occurred?

If you were write a pattern yourself of zeroes and ones, given the information and given a set of n, what would be the probability of that pattern starting with, continuing, and ending with either zeroes or ones given the real information?

A step by step would greatly be appreciated as I intend to do this many many times.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a programming question with Excel as the preferred implementation language.

Comment: Yes it is. But any programming language is fine so long as I can successfully import the data from excel to another program. But I would greatly prefer excel.  Thank you for your interest.

Comment: How long a pattern do you want to look at?  How does that compare to the full length of the data?

Comment: N can be any positive number that is not zero. There are more than 700 binary numbers and that will increase over time. Thank you for your interest.